# Complex problem to solve regarding multiple lists in a dictionary with ranges

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a very complex problem to solve with 5 lists:

```
number = ['1', '2 to 4']
direction = ['direction', 'direction']
place = ['market', 'stadium']
name = ['name', 'name']
street_names = ['baker', '3 streets']
```

and I would like to combine them into a `dictionary` to give me something like:

```
{'1': {'direction': 'market', 'name': 'baker'}, '2': {'direction': 'stadium', 'name': '3 streets'}, '3': {'direction': 'stadium', 'name': '3 streets'}, '4': {'direction': 'stadium', 'name': '3 streets'}}
```

I have already created some kind of formula for the `dictionary`

```
places_dic = {}
for i, index_number in enumerate(number):
    places_dic[index_number] = {str(direction[i]): place[i], (name[i]): street_names[i]}
```

but the result is:

```
{'1': {'direction': 'market', 'name': 'baker'}, '2 to 4': {'direction': 'stadium', 'name': '3 streets'}}
```

which is something I don't want to have.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward solution with no bells and whistles will be to simply check if `to` exists. If so, grab the edges and iterate over the range.

```
places_dic = {}
for i, index_number in enumerate(number):
    if 'to' in index_number:
        start, end = index_number.split(' to ')
        for generated_number in range(int(start), int(end) + 1):
            places_dic[str(generated_number)] = {str(direction[i]): place[i], (name[i]): street_names[i]}
    else:
        places_dic[index_number] = {str(direction[i]): place[i], (name[i]): street_names[i]}
```

`places_dic` is then

```
{'1': {'direction': 'market', 'name': 'baker'},
 '2': {'direction': 'stadium', 'name': '3 streets'},
 '3': {'direction': 'stadium', 'name': '3 streets'},
 '4': {'direction': 'stadium', 'name': '3 streets'}}
```

Of course this can be greatly improved upon, but the general idea will stay the same.